# Open-Source Benchmarks that Measure Compression Speed

Tags: benchmarking, open-source

I'm trying to do an experiment concerning various data-storage formats. I'd like to run an open-source compression benchmark that demonstrates storage format A allows for FASTER compression than format B. However all the open-source benchmarks I find only focus on compression ratio which I'm not interested. Does anyone know of any compression SPEED based benchmarks I can use to demonstrate my results?

Comment: I just happened to come across this page yesterday that seems to reference a compression benchmark: http://www.compressconsult.com/szip/

Comment: Specifically: http://compression.ca/act/

Answer (score 1):

Google's [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli#benchmarks) links to several benchmarks which look to have speed in addition to ratio:

[Squash benchmark](https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/)

[Squash benchmark unstable](https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/unstable/)

[Large text compression benchmark](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html)

[Lzturbo benchmark](https://sites.google.com/site/powturbo/home/benchmark)

Though you would probably need to setup benchmarks yourself